# Facebook shared video redirecting

Tags: facebook, redirect, share

I am using http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=shareurl method to share a video to FB, but I found it is redirecting to the shared page where we shared video. How can I stop redirecting to orignal page and play the video in FB.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly an answer but I am experiencing the same issue.
There is a bug report on facebook here:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/598397860207749?browse=external_tasks_search_results_5286301a489410145241212